# Center overflow element with scrollbar?

Tags: css, layout, scrollbar

I have a layout like [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scrollbarlayout?file=src/app/app.component.ts). I need the green element to be **always centered**, **whatever the screen size**. It works, unless the scrollbar appears.

I've seen in chrome there is 'overflow-y: overlay' css attribute, but I can't find a way to reproduce the same behaviour on other browsers, unless with some javascript (which I would like to avoid for something like this)

**IMPORTANT**: always hiding or showing the scrollbar is not an option!

Is there a way to achieve the wanted result?

Comment: you can try to create a div for the green element and fix it in center with putting green element as 100% to the div.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5ancys0/) for this. Just remove padding from .body and set width as `100% - padding`, like I did.

If you don't want only green div to be scrollable, just move `overflow-y: auto;` to `.container`

```
 .container .body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not exactly the same graphically. I need only the green div to be scrollable (as you correctly pointed out), but the scrollbar has to be shown in the far right of the window (by specifications), not right next the green element